# Run / execute Exchange 2010 Inbox Rules by code

Tags: c#, exchange-server, rules, exchangewebservices

Does anybody know a possibility to run/start/execute the Exchange (2010) Inbox Rules by code?
Not in Outlook, it must run on the Server, best with EWS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. You can parse the rule conditions and actions and execute them yourself against a particular message or a set of messages.